# How to determine which WiFi technology is currently used in connection?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, connection

I would like to check which 'technology' (a/b/g/n) is currently used by my WiFi card for the connection and to check which standards it can use.

How can I check that ?

**EDIT**

Alright, I have tried `sudo lshw -class network` and I got from that :

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:b5100000-b510ffff
```

So I can get form that my card's 'possibilities' `wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn`

but how can I get information about current connection ?

Answer (score 5):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

If you get no response, you may need to install lshw on your system.  You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install lshw
```

Answer (score 3):

I donot know if this is what you are looking for but you can get further information regarding wireless connection from `iwconfig`. Just do `iwconfig WIRELESS_INTERFACE` e.g `iwconfig wlan0`. You can also run `iwlist WIRELESS_INTERFACE OPTIONS`, see man page of `iwlist` for available options. According to man page they both retrieve information from `/proc/net/wireless`

Answer (score 1):

Try and do this

```
lshw -C network
```

It should give you that information.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use `iwconfig`

Can be used without `sudo`

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NETWORK"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=30 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:19   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: This will not give me the actual standard used: `802.11a/b/g/n/ac`